# Writing Tests Using MSTEST with dependent objects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, mstest

I have started writing tests for my project and am stuck at a point where my one object is dependant on another object. The test Framework I am using is MSTEST and I am using .Net 3.5 with visual Studio version 2008.

I would really appreciate, if you can share the best practices using this framework.

Also please let me know any better testing framework under the constraints mentioned above (it should be free to use).

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Dependency Injection. It is a collection of code patterns that allow easier unit testing. I have just finished reading '[Dependency Injection in .NET' by Mark Seemann](http://squadron66.com/index.php?action=download&dir=ufs%2FRIS600+-+Recommended+books&item=Dependency.Injection.in.NET.pdf&order=mod&srt=no) and it covers this problem in great depth. I would recommend it strongly.